# google api, shared contacts with assigned tags

Tags: php, google-api

I'm a newbie with google api, I'd like to assign a tag to some existing shared contacts: is it possible with php code? how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, please introduce yourself to https://stackoverflow.com/help center and correct your question.

Comment: start by digging around in https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/